# raise KeyError (gpr)

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

Sorry for any confusion!! Here is an edited version--I tried to make it minimally reproducible.

```
# embed subject recall in vector space
def run_sts_benchmark(batch):
    sts_encode1 = tf.nn.l2_normalize(embed(tf.constant(batch['sent_1'].tolist())), axis=1)
    sts_encode2 = tf.nn.l2_normalize(embed(tf.constant(batch['sent_2'].tolist())), axis=1)
    cosine_similarities = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(sts_encode1, sts_encode2), axis=1)
    clip_cosine_similarities = tf.clip_by_value(cosine_similarities, -1.0, 1.0)
    scores = 1.0 - tf.acos(clip_cosine_similarities) / math.pi
    return scores
sub = "5ae5e66d3ab2fb0001ef2f3c"
item = "Armor"
df = pd.DataFrame()
# open file that is in a folder called "Armor" && named after subject ID
with open("....directory..../Armor/5ae5e66d3ab2fb0001ef2f3c.csv") as f2:
    next(f2)
    resp = csv.reader(f2)
    resp_list = []
    for row in resp:
        sent_1 = []
        sent = row[0]
        sent_1.append(sent)
        resp_list.append(sent)
        # open answer sheet
        with open("....directory..../answer_sheets/Armor.csv") as f:
            score_key = csv.reader(f)
            for row in score_key:
                sent_2 = row
                # make file col1:subject response, col2: correct answer
                data = pd.DataFrame({"sent_1":sent_1, "sent_2":sent_2})
                # score semantic similarity between response && answer
                score = run_sts_benchmark(data).numpy()
                # binarize semantic similarities
                if score >= threshold:
                    acc = 1
                else:
                    acc = 0
                data['score'] = score
                data['step_acc'] = acc
                df = df.append(data)
# each clause of a subject recall is compared to every clause of an answer sheet and has a similarity score
df_acc = df.groupby('sent_1').sum()
```

The error--

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 6511, in groupby
    return DataFrameGroupBy(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 525, in __init__
    grouper, exclusions, obj = get_grouper(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py", line 781, in get_grouper
    raise KeyError(gpr)
KeyError: 'sent_1'
```

occurs when trying to run the last line. I tried running this outside of the function, scoring one line of a  subject's recall and the error did not occur. Is there a way to avoid this error when iterating through multiple recalls?

Comment: We now know what you are trying to do. And what is your question? Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: I tried running it in PyCharm and get the same error. My question is how do I run the above code and avoid this error?

Comment: Well, this is a method with 6 parameters and we don't know how you call it. Please try to make it a [mre] so that we can reproduce it.

Comment: There is a lot to take in here, and we don't have much information. At the least, could you try adding comments to help people understand what you are trying to achieve in each line of code?